# Merge Multiple Duplicate rows based on multiple columns in Pandas.Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I need to identify duplicate rows based on multiple columns in a Dataframe.
The remaining column (PKID - which has Integer values) should merge as a list of integers.
Example :
Input data :(rows 0 & 1 are duplicates except for PKID column)

```
  Col1  PKID   SUBJECT ID
0  A    58305    ABC    X1
1  A    57011    ABC    X1
2  B    12345    XYZ    X1
```

Expected result :

```
  Col1   PKID            SUBJECT ID
0  A    [58305,57011]    ABC    X1
1  B    12345            XYZ    X1
```

So if all columns except PKID have duplicates, merge all entries as 1 with PKID values being List of Integers.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Do you know what column values can be duplicated?

Comment: Yes, except for Column name PKID, if all other columns have same values, then merge the rows as 1 and make the PKID column's value as a List of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want a `groupby` + `apply`:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['PKID']).tolist())\
                 .PKID.apply(pd.Series.unique).reset_index()

  Col1  ID SUBJECT            PKID
0    A  X1     ABC  [58305, 57011]
1    B  X1     XYZ         [12345]
```